# Edit button for tableview

Tags: xcode, arrays, button, tableview, edit

Can anyone offer assistance with adding a delete button to a tableview in xcode? I can create the button but cannot get it to delete anything in the table. I'm using the default code that comes with the Master Detail Application but have changed the content of the table using an NSObject.

Comment: beg my pardon, but what? please rephrase your question so it is actually clear what you mean :)

Comment: Question now edited, hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the default behaviour of the edit button.

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;`

This will allow you to click and delete any item in the list after it is pressed.

Unless I am misunderstanding how you are using the table item list.